# Странная работа цикла на JS

Tags: javascript, cordova

Вот код:

```
function add_reminder(){
            var i = $("#for_need").val();
            i = parseInt(i,10);
            var text_reminder = '';
            for ( var v = i; v != 0; v--){
              alert(v);
            var filename1 = 'log_weekday' + v + '.txt'; 
            var filename2 = 'log_time' + v + '.txt'; 
            var filename3 = 'log_text' + v + '.txt';
              readFileReminder1(filename1,filename2,filename3,text_reminder,v);
            }
      
    }
```

Почему-то сначала выводится алерты с цифрами цикла, а потом уже выполняется функция, из-за этого значения в функции накладываются друг на друга, и выводится в итоге только одно (последнее) значение, а не то количество, которое было задано в цикле.
Вот код функции:

```
    function readFileReminder1(filename1,filename2,filename3,text_reminder,v){
        var type = window.TEMPORARY;
            var size = 5*1024*1024;
            window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback1, errorCallback)
            
             function successCallback1(fs) {
         fs.root.getFile(filename1, {}, function(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onloadend = function(e){ 
                   text_reminder += "<div class='reminder reminder-" + v + "'>"+
                  "<h4>Уведомление № " + v +"</h4><b><span>" + this.result;
                  readFileReminder2(text_reminder,filename2,filename3,v);
                   //alert('1 read');
                   
               };
               reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorCallback);
         }, errorCallback);
     }

        function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
   }
      }

      function readFileReminder2(text_reminder,filename2,filename3,v){
        var type = window.TEMPORARY;
            var size = 5*1024*1024;
            window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback2, errorCallback)
            
             function successCallback2(fs) {
         fs.root.getFile(filename2, {}, function(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onloadend = function(e){ 
                   text_reminder += " в " + this.result + "</span></b><span> (каждую неделю)</span>";
                   readFileReminder3(text_reminder,filename3,v);
                   //alert('2 read');
                   
               };
               reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorCallback);
         }, errorCallback);
     }

        function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
   }
      }
      function readFileReminder3(text_reminder,filename3,v){
        var type = window.TEMPORARY;
            var size = 5*1024*1024;
            window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback3, errorCallback)

             function successCallback3(fs) {
         fs.root.getFile(filename3, {}, function(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onloadend = function(e){ 
                  text_reminder += "<p>Текст: " + this.result + "</p></div>";
                   //alert('3 read');
                   document.getElementById('reminders').innerHTML = text_reminder;
                   var inputNeed = document.getElementById('v');
                    inputNeed.value = v;

               };
               reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorCallback);
         }, errorCallback);
     }

        function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
   }
      }
```

У кого-нибудь есть предположения, в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

В начале функции поставьте `console.log(...)` и проверьте действительно ли функция выполняется позже всех алертов, или только её продолжение и завершение происходит позже.

Цикл синхронный, а функция асинхронная (с колбэками после задач). Для решения вам нужно перейти на [async/await](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await) или использовать асинхронные циклы, например через библиотеку [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/).

Comment: Списибо, все заработало